# Combine results from multiple queries to as single queryable

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, linq-to-entities

I want to search through a user database and order my results according to how precise the match is. Exact matches on a users name should appear in the result before single word matches, as an example.

This is what i have (the variable 'value' contains a search term and 'query' contains an initial queryable i want to modify)

```
        var values = value.Split(new [] {' ','\t', '\n', '\r'});

        var q1 = query.Where(u => u.Id == valueAsInt || u.ExternalId == valueAsInt);
        var q2 = query.Where(u => u.Name.Contains(value) || u.Username.Contains(value));
        var q3 = query.Where(u => values.All(i => u.Name.Contains(i)) || values.All(i => u.Username.Contains(i)));
        var q4 = query.Where(u => values.Any(i => u.Name.Contains(i)) || values.Any(i => u.Username.Contains(i)));
```

However, I now want to combine the results of q1 through q4 and have a new queryable which i can pass along. I also want to preserve the order of my queries, and frankly I have no idea how to go about doing this..

Comment: You could try concatenating the results. I'm not sure if the order is preserved though. var qAll = q1.Concat(q1).Concat(q2).Concat(q3).Concat(q4);
Would be interesting to see if it works as expected. You could append an extra ordering column for each query to have something to order by though.

Comment: @SilasHansen seems to be working ok, concated all of them together and did a distinct on the result. not sure about the ordering since it turns out the query gets reordered later.

Answer (score 0):

Answered by Silas Hansen in the comments

Answer (score 0):

You should use ranking. e.g.

```
var result = query.Select(u =>
{
    if (u.Id == valueAsInt || u.ExternalId == valueAsInt)
       return new {Rank = 1, Item = u};
    if (u.Name.Contains(value) || u.UserName.Contains(value) )
       return new {Rank = 2, Item = u};
    //Add the other conditions in here
    return new {Rank = 3, Item = u};
}).OrderBy(u => u.Rank).Select(u => u.Item);
```